# React + AJAX component over-rendering

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

To fill the content of React component I use AJAX request in the body of the method componentWillMount, where I change this.state as a result of the execution of the request. The trouble is that the render method runs as before the request completion, as after the this.state change by setState. Moreover, if such component renders one, which also is used AJAX, the number of render calls grows as a power of two.

How to make the component is rendered only after obtaining the necessary data?

```
var News = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            news: [],
            page: 1
        };
    },

    componentWillMount: function () {
        let xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "server/news.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=() => {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) return;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                this.setState({
                    news: eval(xmlhttp.responseText.toString())
                });
            } else {
                handleError(xmlhttp.statusText);
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send('page=' + this.state.page);
        var timeout = setTimeout( function(){ xmlhttp.abort(); handleError("Request time over") }, 10000);
    },

    render: function () {
        let itemList = this.state.news.map(function(item, iterator){
            return (
                <NewsItem
                    niTitle={item[0]}
                    niText={item[1]}
                    niDate={item[2]}
                    niImg={item[3]}
                    key={"ni " + iterator}
                />
            );
        });
        return (
            <div>
                {itemList}
                <PageChanger page={this.state.page}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: @svnav You might consider passing `props` from `<News>` to `<PageChanger>`, and making batch API calls from `<News>`, or a wrapping controller component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to make the component is rendered only after obtaining the
>   necessary data?

If your `render` function returns `false`, nothing will be rendered.
(Source: [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render).)

Therefore, you can set a flag in your initial state:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return { page: 1, shouldRender: false };
}
```

Then, in `render`, you can check that flag:

```
if (! this.state.shouldRender) return false;
```

In the callback passed to the XHR, you can update the flag:

```
this.setState({
  shouldRender: true,
  news: eval(xmlhttp.responseText.toString()),
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I' ve forgot this from the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

First, abstract your network call to a helper and import into the component as needed.

Second, use `componentDidMount` not `componentWillMount` to avoid multiple renders.

for example:

```
import networkCall from ../helpers/networkCall 
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            emails: networkCall.news,
            emailCache: networkCall.page
        });
    },
```